# How to reuse Primefaces datatable with different data in different browser tabs?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, cdi

My application has a query param in the url which is used to render different data using the same xhtml (all dynamic content) in a datatable.

Scope of the bean is session scope, the datatable renders all data, and has lots of input elements which open different dialogs.

If I open another browser tab sending a different query param, the datatable renders perfectly, however if I go back to the first tab, all commandlinks won't invoke the actions and the whole application will start to act very erratically.

According to my research this is because I changed the data in the datatable, I tried naming it with dynamic ids, dynamic widget names, but nothing seems to work.

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="param" value="#{moduleBean.param}"/>
  <f:viewAction action="#{moduleBean.setup}" />
</f:metadata>

<c:set var="module" value="#{moduleBean.param}" />

<p:dataTable id="#{module}-dataTable" value="#{moduleBean.model[module]}" var="data">

  <p:commandLink action="#{moduleBean.openModuleDetails}" update=":#{module}-searchDialog" oncomplete="PF('#{module}-searchWidget').show();">
    <f:param name="module" value="#{module}" />
    <f:param name="dataRow" value="#{data.dbKey}" />
  </p:commandLink>
</p:dataTable>


@Named
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
public class ModuleBean implements Serializable {

   private String param;

   public void setup() throws IOException {
      this.model.put(this.param, new LazyDataModel(this.param));
   }

    public Map<String, LazyDataModel> getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

This builds all the expected html with all correct ids in each tab, however JSF is still not processing the action inside the commandlink. Needless to say, if I stick to only one browser tab everything works perfectly.

Sometimes it starts working after clicking twice in the link, but going back and forth between the browser tabs will eventually always crash it.

Adding an action listener to the commandlink didnt fix it either.

Any suggestions on how to make JSF treat the same datatable as different entities on the same page but with different parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about the underlying bean - if you place your `moduleBean` in `@SessionScoped` this would be the expected behavior. The session (and session scoped beans) are shared between browser tabs. So you cannot rely on the underlying values from two different tabs.

Try changing to `@RequestScoped/@ViewScoped` for the backing values of the table data.

Here is a complete solution that works, note that this uses PrimeFaces 6.2, Apache Commons and Lombok;

```
@Data
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TableTestBackingBean implements Serializable {
    private int param;

    @Inject
    private PersonsBean personsBean;

    public void onClicked() {
        System.out.println("Clicked fine!");
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return personsBean.getPersons()[param];
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@ApplicationScoped
public class PersonsBean {
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int age;
    }

    private List<Person> persons[];

    @PostConstruct void init() {
        persons = new List[4];

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            persons[j] = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                final String firstName =
                    RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
                final String lastName = 
                    RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
                final int age = RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 120);

                persons[j].add(new Person(firstName, lastName, age));
            }
        }
    }   
 }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="param" value="#{tableTestBackingBean.param}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:head>
            <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:dataTable value="#{tableTestBackingBean.persons}" var="t">
            <p:column headerText="First Name"><h:outputText value="#{t.firstName}" /></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Last Name"><h:outputText value="#{t.lastName}" /></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Age"><h:outputText value="#{t.age}" /></p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton action="#{tableTestBackingBean.onClicked}" value="Click Me!" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This uses an application scoped bean for the table data, keeping it completely static. This works without a hitch and the table renders the data differently based on the parameter passed in `param`.

Comment: Better to use a `@ViewScoped` bean for the ajax pagination, filtering and selection

Comment: I know they are shared, thats why my model which return the paginated results to the datatable is a map, thats get accessed by the param sent by the view. I keep all paginated results and data in the backing bean, so it should still take the correct one. Unfortunately its not enough to make it work

Comment: ViewScoped isnt working for some reason at all. Thats why Im using session

Comment: But `#{moduleBean.param}` is shared too so effectively identical for all pages. And then the initial model for page one differs from the one used when you opened page2. If you do not use the c:set but always directly use the param it might work too. And you effextively created a windowscoped  which I meant to suggest to use. See deltaspike!

Comment: I actually checked and #{moduleBean.param} is not the same for all pages. It actually resolves to the correct query param sent, and use that to name all tables and components, works at view, and works in backing bean. Its just that the datatable is getting somehow confused

Comment: Did you use the correct `@ViewScoped` ? Make sure you use the one in `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` if this is a CDI application.

Comment: I'm guessing the `c:set` is there to set the parameter and handle some internal state in the session bean ? This is probably what is causing your problems - because it's going to be different between the tabs.

Comment: Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class ModuleBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named]

Comment: Yes. In plain english this means "add Serializable", so just add an `implements Serializable` to the bean :)

Comment: Correct, the c:set is for getting which datatable is rendered in the current tab. Its just the key to access the map of the lazy datatable full object.

Comment: Using the viewscope is doing exactly the same as the sessionscope, datatable still wont call the action in first tab

Comment: If you show us the bean we might be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: The code is still incomplete. The reason I ask is because I need to check where all values are coming from. Something has to be in the wrong scope for the behavior to occur that you are experiencing (or some similar issue). If your action callback is not being called at all then the viewstate is somehow being affected as well. Are you using `@PostConstruct` or the constructor for initializing values for example ?

Comment: Im not using any postconstruct, and there are no other scopes anywhere, This is the minimal example on which the issue happens

Comment: You said your action callback was not getting called - is your `p:commandLink` placed inside a `h:form` ?

Comment: Yes it is, again .. it's not being called only when using 2 tabs, everything works perfectly when using just one tab.

Comment: Yes but as I don't have the full code, invalid use can also result in unexpected behavior and at this point you are forcing me to guess.

I just did a test here locally with PrimeFaces 6.2 doing something similar and its working just fine even if I use ten tabs - so clearly something in the code is causing this behavior. One difference is that I used `value="#{moduleBean.model"}` directly though and relied on the backing bean value set by `<c:set>` when returning the value. I don't think that's the issue though.

Comment: The moduleBean param is different for each tab when opening a new tab. Since there is one instance, it will  after openening a new tab be the same for tab one. And I corrected myself that it should be windowscoped here.

Comment: Please note that @WindowScoped is a DeltaSpike extension.

Comment: Using value="#{moduleBean.model"} in the datatable and handling that in the backing bean made no difference. I'm really stucked with this.

Comment: Updated the answer with the test code I used  here. I hope it helps.